# Is predicting (in the limit) computable sequences as hard as the halting problem?

Tags: computability

**Question**:
Is predicting (as defined below) computable sequences as hard as the halting problem?

**Elaboration**:
"Predict" means successfully predict, which means make only finitely many errors on the task of trying to predict the n-th bit of the sequence given access to the previous n-1 bits (starting from the first bit and going through the entire infinite computable sequence).

There's a simple diagonalization argument (due to Legg 2006) that for any Turing machine predictor p, there's a computable sequence on which it makes infinitely many errors. (Construct a sequence that has as its nth term the opposite of what p predicts given the previous n-1 terms in the sequence.) So there is no computable predictor that predicts every computable sequence. A halting oracle would allow construction of such a predictor. But can you show that having such a predictor allows you to solve the halting problem?

**More elaboration**

**Definition** (Legg)

A *predictor* p is a Turing machine that tries to predict the n-th bit of a sequence S given access to the previous n-1 bits. If the prediction fails to match the n-th bit of the sequence, we call this a *mistake*. We will say that p *predicts* S if p only makes finitely many mistakes on S. In other words, p predicts S if there is some number M in the sequence s.t. for every m>M, p correctly predicts the m-th bit of S given access to the first m-1 bits.

Formally, we could define a predictor machine as having three tapes. The sequence is entered as input bit-by-bit on one tape, the predictions for the next bit are made on a second tape (the machine can only move right across this tape), and then there is a work tape on which the machine can move in both directions.

**Simple results**
By the above definition, there's a predictor that predicts all the rational numbers. (Use the standard zig-zag enumeration of the rationals. Start by predicting the 1st rational in the list, if there's a mistake, move to the next rational.). By a similar argument, there's a predictor s.t. given access to N, is able to predict all sequences of Kolomogorov complexity less than or equal to N. (Run all the N-bit machines in parallel and take the prediction of the machine that halts first. You can only make finitely many errors).

*Citation*
Shane Legg 2006
http://www.vetta.org/documents/IDSIA-12-06-1.pdf
(not the author of this post)

Answer (score 11):

Actually this is easier than solving the halting problem.

Let $f:\mathbb N\rightarrow\mathbb N$ be a function that dominates all computable functions, i.e., for all total computable functions $g:\mathbb N\rightarrow\mathbb N$, we have that for all but finitely many $n$, $g(n)\le f(n)$. It is a standard fact that there exist such functions that have strictly lower Turing degree than the halting problem, see e.g. Soare's book *Recursively Enumerable Sets and Degrees*. These are called the *high* Turing degrees.

Let $\varphi_e$, $e\in\mathbb N$ be a standard list of the partial computable functions from $\mathbb N$ to $\{0,1\}$.

Now, using $f$ we construct a predictor $p$.

$p(a_0,\ldots,a_{k-1})$ is chosen as some number $a_{k}\in \{0,1\}$ so as to make the sequence $a_0,\ldots,a_k$ agree with $\varphi_t(0),\ldots,\varphi_t(k)$ for the minimal possible $t\le k$. Since we cannot wait for possibly hanging computations to halt, we only monitor the computations until stage $f(k)$ ($f(k)$ many computations steps). If there is no such $t$ we just set $a_{k}$ arbitrarily (say $=0$).

Now suppose $q$ is minimal such that $\varphi_q$ computes the computable sequence that is actually observed. Then we will for all but finitely many $k$ use $t=q$ and hence choose the correct $a_{k}$, because $f$ dominates the *running time function* for $\varphi_q$, namely $s(n)=$ the least stage where $\varphi_q(n)$ has halted.

Comment: This is in fact [uniformly equivalent to computing a dominating function](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/21073/6973). ​ ​